# JSInterface from webview undefined when backing to previous activity

Tags: android, android-webview, android-activity

I got a webview, which has a JSInterface :

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterfacelistArticle(mWebView, this, website), "interfaceWebsite");
```

When I use javascript function to call functions from my interface :

```
window.interfaceWebsite.doToast(info);
```

It's working fine the first time, but when my activity finish(), and then I come back to this one, I got this error :

```
E/Web Console(28654): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'doToast' of undefined at :1
```

Why my interface is not working when I start my activity a second time ?

Edit: 
If I remove window. when I call a function, I got :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: interfaceWebsite is not defined at :1
```

So I'm sure my interface has a problem when loading for a second time...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overwritted my loadurl function for my webview :

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
               @Override
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
                   loadingFinished = false;
                   mWebView.loadUrl(urlNewString);
                   return true;
               }

               @Override
               public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                   super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                   loadingFinished = true;
                }
            });
```

I needed to set loadingFinished into a static variable sometimes ago, but I forgot that my var will not be updated when I create a new instance of my activity : just need to set loadingFinish at false;

**Now, my thread wait until my webview load the website completely**

Yeah, pretty stupid.

Answer (score -2):

At the beginning at you script, add:

```
while(typeof JSInterface === "undefined"){  }
```

This will "wait" for JSInterface to load, not perfect, but it works really well